# How to size boxes in flex-box flex wrap?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I've been trying to make just a simple footer with 4 boxes, which should wrap and stack into a column. However each box must have width equal to 25%, but when I do this using percentages (%) it will not wrap (at all), leaving me to go back to pixels, which isn't ideal for responsiveness.

Could there be a workaround that I'm possibly missing?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-container>div {
  color: teal;
  background: white;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 300px; // box must not be in % otherwise dont work. Bug?
  font-weight: 800;
  h3 {
    color: $smokey;
  }
  a:active,
  a:hover,
  a:visited,
  a:focus {
    color: $smokey;
  }
  ul {
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: $light;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <h3>Lyntree</h3>
    <ul class="ft-lks">
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Framework</h3>
    <ul class="ft-lks">

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Support</h3>
    <ul class="ft-lks">
      <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Support Base</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Report a Bug</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submit Ticket</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Support</h3>
    <div class="ft-at">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Might I add, I saw another post about containing a max-width at 100% for the parent container, but I have tried this and it didn't work either. I have also tried it in Mozilla + Chrome?

Comment: Width should be in %, thats not a bug. can you add the html part too.

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap` means that the flex items will `wrap` into a **new** row when there is a "overflow". But I understand your question in that way, that you want only **one** single row, don't yo? Then you should use `flex-wrap: nowrap;`.

Comment: I even tried this page - https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_wrap and as soon as I place the percentages, it just refuses to wrap that's the weird thing. I want it to wrap as a 1 one column if that makes sense

Comment: which should wrap and stack into a column: you want them to stack in a single line, 4 boxes vertically aligned? you desired result is a bit confusing, clearify pls

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: I can't say that I've ever needed to use flex-grow before but I'll the example below ago, thank you for this. Thought something like as this so simple, would have been a lot simpler. :) Thank you for this x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mix up `flex-wrap` and `flex-grow` properties? With `flex-wrap: wrap` the flex-items (children) will *wrap* into a new row when there is not enough space for the children. `flex-grow` scales the flex-children size.

Take a look at my example below. I added two `footer` with a `flex-container`. I think you want to archive the first setup. The second setup has also the class `wrap` which lets the flex-items wrap into new lines. Because all `flex-items` have `width: 100%;`, they wrap into **four** rows.

```css
.footer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.flex-container{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* is default */
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 64px;
}

.wrap{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container > .flex-item:nth-child(1){
    background: red;
}
.flex-container > .flex-item:nth-child(2){
    background: green;
}
.flex-container > .flex-item:nth-child(3){
    background: grey;
}
.flex-container > .flex-item:nth-child(4){
    background: orange;
}

.flex-item{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="flex-container wrap">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```